# How can I give my .vst3 plugin to someone else?

Tags: vst

I developed a vst3 plug-in on my own with the sdk. 
Now I would like to give it to a friend of mine. But I don't know how to give it to him.

I developed the plugin with the sdk, on Xcode. So my plug-in appears in VST_SDK/build/VST3/Debug with the name MyPlugin.vst3. When the plug-in is located here, Reaper and PremierePro are able to recognize it. (I told Reaper and premiere to scan this location). 
But when I try to move my plug-in to the default location for this kind of plugin (/Library/Audio/Plug-ins/VST, which Reaper and Premiere recognise by default), The softwares aren't able to recognise my plugin anymore.

I'll try to be clear with my expectations. 
I want to give my plugin to someone else. I thought I just had to give the .vst3 and put it in the good location, but it doesn't seem to work.

Maybe it is a license problem ? or maybe I have to give the whole sdk ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: What other files are in your debug folder? Make sure you also move all the dependent library files etc. (disclaimer: don't know Mac or XCode)

Comment: They aren't any files except for my .vst3 in the debug folder. 
I thought that when you build a .vst3 all the files from the sdk needed are "inside" the .vst3, is it wrong ? maybe if I move the .vst3 it doesn't recognize the dependencies anymore.

Comment: If all the dependencies are inside the .vst3, it should not need to recognize anything else, right? I would try to look for some logging output. Can you let the DAW/Host log plugin load errors? Or look at the OS error log? Or try a different DAW/Host that does have extra logging/diagnostic features? [2c]

Comment: Yes that's why I think that the dependencies aren't in the .vst3
I will try, maybe I can have information by watching the errors in the working case scenario too.

Comment: Ok. I found the problem. 
I don't really understand why if I move my .vst3 to /Library/Audio/Plugins/VST3 it isn't recognise, maybe it is a problem of access right. 
But in fact if I move it to User/MyUserName/Library/Audio/Plugins/VST3 it works perfectly fine !!
I just couldn't see the existence of this repository, I didn't know that on Mac it is a hidden repository. 
So yeah for people with the same questions just move your .vst3 to this hidden User/blablaname/Library/Audio/Plugin/VST3 repository and it's perfect.

Comment: You should put that up as an answer (to your own question) [2c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem. I don't really understand why if I move my .vst3 to /Library/Audio/Plugins/VST3 it isn't recognise, maybe it is a problem of access right. But in fact if I move it to User/MyUserName/Library/Audio/Plugins/VST3 it works perfectly fine !! I just couldn't see the existence of this repository, I didn't know that on Mac it is a hidden repository. So yeah for people with the same questions just move your .vst3 to this hidden User/blablaname/Library/Audio/Plugin/VST3 repository and it's perfect. –